# Visual Studio - disable reversed cursor to select line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I hope this is okay to ask on SO, I'm not sure. I apologize if it shouldn't be here.

I reinstalled Visual Studio Professional 2015 yesterday due to a few issues I was having. With the new installation, my line numbers have a very wide section where the mouse reverses direction and select the entire line if clicked. I don't recall this area being so wide on any of my previous installations of VS2015; I know it was there in the first place. Is there a way to disable this?

This is the area where this happens, boxed in green. It's much wider than the line numbers fill (only 147 lines in this file).

[image: area in which the cursor reverses]

Comment: This has been a feature since before VS2008...

Comment: @Casey I'm relatively new to VS. I know this was there, but IIRC the bar wasn't _nearly_ as wide. If there's no way to adjust it, post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: The extra space you noticed is for the 'light bulb' feature in VS2015. No way that I know of to remove this from the margin area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two "margins" available in Visual Studio 2015: Selection and Indicator available under `Tools > Options > Text Editor > General > Display`. Turning these off remove some, but not all of the "extra space" and the feature of highlighting an entire line is still there.

If you want to turn them off because the extra space is bothersome, keep in mind you will not be able to see breakpoints unless "highlight current line" is checked.

Comment: Disabling `Indicator margin` hides breakpoints, but hiding `Selection margin` still shows them while making the margin narrower. Thank you!

Comment: I think the option is called "highlight *entire* line". Something I quite like because it makes the breakpoints easier to see, maximizes space on the screen for code, and doesn't matter much to me that I can't click to set a breakpoint since F9 does just as good a job.